# How to reduce vertical spacing between two web part zones?

Tags: 2010, page-layout, web-part-zone

I've defined two Web Part Zones in the page layout, with nothing between them.

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Zone 1" ID="Zone1" Orientation="Horizontal"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Zone 2" ID="Zone2" Orientation="Horizontal"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

I've placed a CEWP in each zone. Once the page is out of edit mode, it renders like this:

[image: Spacing between two Web Part Zones]

How can I reduce the vertical spacing highlighted by the orange arrows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created `/Style Library/CollapsedWebPartZones.css`...

```
.CollapsedWebPartZones table.s4-wpTopTable { 
    padding: 0px; 
} 
.CollapsedWebPartZones table { 
    width: auto; 
}
```

... and referenced it from the top of my page layout file's `PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead` content placeholder:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <link id="CollapsedWebPartZonesStyleLink" href="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/CollapsedWebPartZones.css%>" runat="server" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <etc>  
    <etc>  
    <etc>  
</asp:Content>
```

Lastly, I added a `class="CollapsedWebPartZones"` attribute to the markup element in the page layout which *contained* the web part zones (a table row in my case -- `<tr>`).

Result:

[image]

Comment: Did You try it for 2013 version?